# How to add function app keys to logicapp app settings through Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am creating logic app and function app through Bicep configuration but need to update logicapp app settings with function app master key.

Below is the Bicep template:

```
resource funcapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-01-15' = {
  name: funcappname
  location: Location
  tags: tags
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    serverFarmId: spfuncapp.id
    ...
  }
}

resource logicappsite 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-01-15' = {
  name: logicapp
  location: Location
  tags: tags
  kind: 'functionapp,workflowapp'
  properties: {
    enabled: true
    serverFarmId: spD365LogicApp.id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          'name': 'azureFunctionOperation_functionAppKey'
          'value': '<function app master key here?'
        }
        ...
      ]
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I add function app master key to logic app settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the master key using the `listKeys` function:

```bicep
listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/host', funcappname, 'default'), '2022-03-01').masterKey
```

In you case, you could write something like that:

```bicep
appSettings = [
  {
    'name': 'azureFunctionOperation_functionAppKey'
    'value': listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/host', funcapp.name, 'default'), '2022-03-01').masterKey
  }
]
```

Comment: @thanks Thomas,   does it work if add like below on logic app settings 

'name': 'azureFunctionOperation_functionAppKey'
'value': ${listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/host', funcappname, 'default'), '2022-03-01').masterKey}

Comment: you don't need the `${}` as the masterkey is already a string. Update my answer.